# AngularJS ng-change doesn't work on checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a list of to-dos with checkboxes. Checked boxes are marked as "Done" to-dos and unchecked ones are marked as "Undone". Everything is working fine when I check then uncheck an initially unchecked box. It correspondingly being marked "Done" when checked, then "Undone" when I uncheck it back.

But, the problem goes when I uncheck an initially checked box. Nothing happens. It should suppose to be marked as "Undone" because I unchecked it. After that, I would check back the box and there the `ng-change` triggers but it doesn't mark the to-do as "Done" but "Undone", when a checked box should supposedly be a "Done" to-do.

**HTML**:

```
<input icheck type="checkbox"
       ng-model="toDo.value.members.status.value"
       ng-change="vm.markAs(toDo.value.instanceId)"
       ng-click="vm.markAs(toDo.value.instanceId)"
       ng-init="toDo.value.members.status.value === 'Undone'"
       ng-checked="toDo.value.members.status.value === 'Done'">
<span class="m-l-xs">{{ toDo.value.title }}</span>
```

**Controller**:

```
function markAs(id) {    
    todolistService.getToDo(id).then(function (response) {
        vm.toDoStatus = response.data.members.status.value;
        if (vm.toDoStatus == 'Undone') {
            console.log('Done');
            todolistService.markAsDone(id).then(function () {
                notifyService.success($translate.instant('MSG_TODO_MARK_AS_DONE_SUCCESS'));
            }, function (error) {
                notifyService.showError(error);
            });
        } else if (vm.toDoStatus == 'Done') {
            console.log('Undone');
            todolistService.markAsUndone(id).then(function () {
                notifyService.success($translate.instant('MSG_TODO_MARK_AS_UNDONE_SUCCESS'));
            }, function (error) {
                notifyService.showError(error);
            });
        }
    }, function (error) {
        notifyService.showError(error);
    });
}
```

I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: It's because the status is not instantiated. Then status is not equal to 'Done' or 'Undone' he's null or empty. `Add vm.toDoStatus == 'Undone' || vm.toDoStatus == undefined`

Comment: is it normal to use ng-model and ng-checked at the same time ?

Comment: A checkbox ng-model is a boolean value. So `toDo.value.members.status.value` should be true or false not `Undone` (`ng-init="toDo.value.members.status.value === 'Undone'"`).

Comment: also what's the point in using `ng-change` and  `ng-click` on a checkbox at the same time?

Comment: Thanks @Alexis but where do I put `vm.toDoStatus == 'Undone' || vm.toDoStatus == undefined`?

Comment: @MayK @TJ I was only trying out something and forgot to remove `ng-click` that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
function markAs(id) {
```

To:

```
vm.markAs = function(id) {
```

Comment: No, I actually declared the method `markAs` above my controller, so there's nothing wrong with that: `vm.markAs = markAs;`

Comment: Can you link to a page with the code then so we get the whole picture?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the status is not instantiated.

Then status is not equal to 'Done' or 'Undone' he's null or empty.

try

```
if(vm.toDoStatus == 'Undone' || vm.toDoStatus == undefined)
```

Instead of

```
if (vm.toDoStatus == 'Undone')
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing really changed. As you can see, I put `console.log`s in both conditions, but when I uncheck an initially checked box, it doesn't go to inside the `else if (vm.toDoStatus == 'Done')` condition. But when I check it back, it goes inside to that condition, which is wrong.

Comment: Okay, try to log the status at the initial check

Comment: The status on initial check is just fine. The status on initial check of a checked box cannot be read. I don't know if there's something wrong with my condition or to `ng-change` itself.

Comment: Ok so it's because your object don't exist at the initial check. So you haven't any id in parameter